# Is it possible to install Wordpress inside of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a question. I have a Wordpress site that I built for a client and they were acquired and the company that bought them is shuttering the website and folding it into their existing site.

My website is based on Wordpress. I want to clone the client site and run a copy to show to potential new clients. If I have http://example.com and I wanted to put a Wordpress install inside of it at: http://example.com/demo/site or http://example.com/client_site. Is this possible? Are there any red flags or warnings that I should be worried about?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just install a fresh copy of Wordpress in the subdirectory...

Comment: Thanks! I thought you could. I just wanted to be sure!

Comment: Yes you can install as a subdirectory in one wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that, I have done this in [serverwarrior](http://serverwarrior.com)  It is an wordpress site and [wooshop](http://serverwarrior.com/wooshop/)  this is another wordpress site inside that.

Just extract the WordPress zip file inside  the directory you are having your site wordpress and rename the new wordpress folder to any name you want.