# Wordpress subdirectory not loading css, js

Tags: wordpress

I had installed Wordpress project in root directly. Then I had installed another project in a subdirectory. Now it shows multiple issue.

Below url works -

```
www.domain.com/subdirectory/
```

But this won't work, show max redirect issue.

```
www.domain.com/subdirectory/wp-admin
```

If I browse root URL, it redirects to subdirectory url.

Also css, js not loading for below url

```
www.domain.com/subdirectory/link_to_css_js
```

But works for below link -

```
www.domain.com/link_to_css_js
```

In CPANEL, WP Toolkit, I can see only one project with url `www.domain.com/subdirectory/`, don't see any project with root url.

Can someone guide me to investigate the issue. I am just starting with Wordpress.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials out there if you search for "install wordpress in a wordpress subdirectory" - this should get you started: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-step-by-step/

Comment: Someone already installed the project, Actually it was in another server, then someone migrate it to current server. Now its showing this issues. I am trying to debug the cause.

Comment: Follow the tutorials anyway...even if it is already installed. Maybe a step was missed when the migration happened. The `.htaccess` might need to be updated on the new server.

Comment: I managed to make it work by setting site_url(sub_directory wp-config.php) to root domain

Answer (score 0):

If you used cPanel to create the WordPress sites, then it's likely that some config was messed up when creating the subdirectory.

This answer is from 2015, but would indicate that it is possible:
[Is it possible to install Wordpress inside of Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620925/is-it-possible-to-install-wordpress-inside-of-wordpress)

Comment: Probably but how can I debug and fix the config?

Comment: Not sure. If the sites are brand new, then I'd destroy them both, and manually (not with cPanel) create both installs.

Comment: very old project, moved from one server to another

Comment: Likely then you'll need to do some experimenting on a separate server to figure out  workable setup and transition.